# Why I am getting an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at app.js:1:19' when using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

My problem is that when I try to run my code using require('puppeteer') then I get an error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at app.js:1:19'

HTML

```
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="url" name="" id="image_input">
        <button id="image_downloader">Search</button>
    </form>
    <section id="image">
            
    </section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
const puppetter = require('puppeteer');

const image_input = document.querySelector('#image_input');
const image_downloader = document.querySelector('#image_downloader');
const section_image = document.querySelector('#image');

let image_link_value;
image_downloader.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    image_link_value = image_input.value;
    const createImage = document.createElement('img');
    section_image.append(createImage);
    createImage.setAttribute('src',`${image_link_value}`);
    puppetter_call();
})

function puppetter_call(){
    const openBrowser = puppetter.launch({headless:false});
    let page;
    openBrowser
        .then(function(browser){
            const pageArrPromise = browser.pages();
            return pageArrPromise;
        })
        .then(function(browserPage){
            page = browserPage[0];
            let gotoPromise = page.goto(`${image_link_value}`);
            return gotoPromise
        })
}
```

Comment: or [is there a way to use require.js for using puppeteer in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61297011)

Comment: When asking a question, it's always a good idea to [share what you're _really_ trying to achieve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876). What's your goal here? As is, we can tell you why the error happens (you can't run Puppeteer in a web browser), but we can't really help you get to whatever your underlying goal might be, the thing that running Puppeteer in a web browser is designed to do for you. As an aside, `then` is going to be much more awkward than `await` for usage with Puppeteer. As you move the code to Node, I suggest using `await`.